# When did Gringo saved Javi for the first time?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, get-the-gringo

In *Get The Gringo (2012)*, Gringo kills Carnal who trying to rape Kid's mom.
Carnal also attacks Caracas who tried to stops him. Actually Carnal is the cousin to Javi & Javi's brother is Caracas. So when Javi tries to kill Gringo then Gringo convinces him to not to kill him by saying this words:

> I saved you the embarrassment of having family blood on your hands.
>   And if he was willing to kill your brother, he was coming to kill you
>   next.In about a minute and a half, to be precise. So, I saved your
>   f*cking life **twice**.

But he used the word twice instead of once which makes me rewatch the movie, but nowhere 
he saved Javi twice?